# difference between kendo.navigate and changing location.hash

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am using Kendo mobile library to develop the mobile app.

I am having a problem when I use:

```
   kendo.navigate("some-view-id");
```

It throws:

```
   Uncaught typeError: Cannot call method 'navigate' of undefined at file ...
```

**Note: This error just occurs on android version 4.3  version 2.3.3 works perfect**

So Now I am changing the location.hash in order to navigate betwee kendo views.

```
   location.hash= "#some-view-id"
```

I know it is not a good practice. But it is working for now;

My question what is the difference of using kendo.navigate() and changing location.hash? In other words, what does navigation function does as an added value?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the documentation of the [kendo Object in Kendo API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo) didn't mention about the method `navigate`.

If you are using kendo mobile, you should be able to call it:

```
app.navigate('#some-view-id');
```

And it work for me on any devices between iOS 6 and iOS 8, and between Android 2.3.6 to Android 4.4.

I think they are using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) method to navigate, and the rest of the things will be handled by kendo router.